# trouble creating a 4d maze generation algorithm

Tags: java

So I am interested in creating a 4 dimensional maze such that

```
boolean[][][][] myMaze=new boolean[x][y][z][w];
public static void doMazeStuff(){
    //maze implementation here
    // true=wall;
    // false is empty 
}
```

Could someone show me how to do this? This is all I know how to do:

```
public static void terribleMaze(){
    for(int a=0;a<x;a++){
        for(int b=0;b<x;b++){
            for(int c=0;c<x;c++){
                for(int d=0;d<x;c++){
                    if(math.random()<.1/*"maze" density"*/){
                        maze[a][b][c][d]=true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I know my implementation is terrible. Could someone help me out here?

I know my implementation is garbage. This is for a personal project. It should ideally at least look like a maze.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a personal project and you do not know what you are doing here, which it looks like you dont(sorry), I would recommend starting with a 2D maze. There are many different ways to make a 2D maze and all the algorithm pseudo code has already been made and is easy to find. In my undergraduate classes we used the common depth-first search, randomized kruskals, and prims.

Comment: No offense taken. (I just learnt java and I just thought it would be interesting to get a 4d maze thing working.